# Save SMTP mails in database instead of sending

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

I have an application using JavaMail that sends mail via a SMTP server.
For testing purpose, I do not want to saturate the SMTP server, so I want to know if I can save all the mails in a database on SMTP server to check if the mail has benn sent, but not send them really?
If it's possible, what is the best way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on your SMTP server.

There are several SMTP servers intended for testing only; search for "smtp testing server".